# How would you do this basic wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm starting to develop it and I realise it's kind of tricky.
I need to convert the shortcode

```
[helloworld] into <h1>"Hello World"</h1>
```

and be able to change

```
"Hello World" from admin
```

Can someone point me on the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need create `hellowrold` as a shortcode.

```
function hellowrold_func( $atts ) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'content' => 'Default content',
    ), $atts );

    return "<h1>{$a['content']}</h1>";
}
add_shortcode( 'hellowrold', 'hellowrold_func' );
```

Then you can use it like this and change text as you like from the content attribute.

```
[hellowrold content="Hello World"]
```

See [Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) for more details.

If you need to add this to a plugin, simply create a file with a header content like this:

```
/**
 * Plugin Name: YOUR PLUGIN NAME
 */
```

Add the code above below this header and put the file inside a folder in your plugins directory.

See [Plugins Basics](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/header-requirements/) for more details.

Comment: This was really helpful! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome @Simon, don't forget to mark the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

For such kind of purpose, you need to use **shortcode_atts** (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/shortcode_atts/).

Simply define the below function

```
function torque_hello_world_shortcode( $atts ) {
   $a = shortcode_atts( array(
      'title' => 'Heading'
   ), $atts );
   return '<h1>"' . $a["title"] . '"</h1> from admin';
}
```

To use the above function, simply add the below shortcode .....

```
1. [helloworld title="Hello World"]
returns
"Hello World" from admin

2. [helloworld title="Hi"]
returns
"Hi" from admin
```

Comment: This was really helpful! Thank you!